# How to send image in postman in laravel

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am using laravel lumen to make API. I have to convert and save blade file in image and have to send image path in api.

How to do that? I am not getting idea. I tried by below code-

[how to convert view file in image and return in api in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296097/how-to-convert-view-file-in-image-and-return-in-api-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment110177430_62296097)

But not working. 
What I am doing wrong? Or any other solution?

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and **code** to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is about sending image using postMan:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39663104/10573560

Comment: Sorry. it is not my answer.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/sx1p3l

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660074/post-image-data-using-postman check out this