# how to resolve an error to use spatie laravel

Tags: laravel, lumen, browsershot

I am using spatie library in laravel lumen to create file into image. But it is giving error.

```
$destinationPath = storage_path('uploads');
$new_path = str_replace('\\', '/', $destinationPath);

Browsershot::url('https://www.example.com/')
    ->setScreenshotType('jpeg', 100)
    ->save($new_path);
```

Error is:
The given path **'your storage file path'** did not contain an extension. Please append an extension.

Comment: You are only supplying the folder path, shouldn't you supply the full path including a filename in the save method? The filename should include an extension, so the system knows what image type to save.